# Published Workbook or Dashboards takes quite long time to open in Tableau server

Tags: tableau-api

I am using `Tableau Desktop 8.2` and `Tableau server 8.2 (Licensed versions)` , the workbook created in Tableau are successfully published to `Tableau server.`

But when the `user want to see the views or workbooks it takes a very long time to preview or open?`
The Workbooks are created with `Amazon RedShift Database having (>5 million records)`

Could somebody guide me on this? like what is it taking a long to preview or open even after being published to `Tableau server?`

Comment: First question, are the views performant when opened using only Tableau Desktop? Get them working well on Desktop before introducing Server into the mix. then look at the logs in My Tableau Repository which include query strings and timing info to see if you can narrow down the cause. You can also try the Performance Recorder feature

Comment: Following on from Alex's suggestion, the next thing to try is to install Tableau Desktop on the Tableau Server machine, then retest

Comment: @Talvalin : is it necessary that Tableau server/Desktop has to be on the same machine? in my  case i did reports in local machine and Tableau server is on the remote desktop(RDP)..

Comment: If the report is slow in Tableau Desktop on the server machine then it's environmental (machine/network). If it's not then it might be  a Tableau Server issue

Answer (score 1):

First question, are the views performant when opened using only Tableau Desktop? Get them working well on Desktop before introducing Server into the mix.

then look at the logs in My Tableau Repository which include query strings and timing info to see if you can narrow down the cause. You can also try the Performance Recorder feature.

A typical problem is an overly expensive query just to display a dashboard. In that case, simplify. Start with a simple high level summary viz and the introduce complexity testing the impact on performance. If one viz is too slow, there are usually alternative approaches available

Comment: thanks.. i'm quite new to all this stuff.. one more suggestion i got like i need to create an extract of Data i used and publish it on server.. will this get an performance impact?

Comment: An extract will be more performant than a live connection, since all of the required data will already be on the localhost

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with Alex; I had a similar issue with HP Vertica. I had lot of action set on the dashboard. Considering the database structure is final, I did created the tableau extract and used the Online tableau extract in place of live connection. Vola! that solved my problem and the users are happy with the response time as well. Hope this helps you too..

Answer (score 0):

Tableau provides two mode of data refreshes:

> **Live** : Tableau will execute underlying queries every time the
>   dashboard is referred / refreshed. Apart from badly formulated
>   queries, this is one of the reason why your dashboard on Tableau Online
>   might take forever to load.
>
> **Extract** : Query will be executed once, according to (your) specified
>   schedule and same data will reflect everytime the dashboard is
>   refreshed.

In extract mode, the time is taken only when the extract is being refreshed. However, if the extract is not refreshed periodically, the same, stale data will reflect on the dashboard. Thus, extract view is not recommended for representations of live data.

You can toggle Live <--> Extract from the **Data Source** pane of Tableau Desktop. (refer top right of the snapshot).

[image]